# PF Push counter example won't work with ajax

Tags: ajax, sockets, primefaces, push

I've had problems using PF Push (PF 5.3) on WebSphere Portal 7, so I tried push using PF 4. I used counter example from docs for testing purposes.

web.xml

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

bean (application scope):

```
private int count;

public void setCount(int count) {
   this.count = count;
}

public int getCount() {
   return count;
}

public synchronized void increment() {
      count++;
      PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
      pushContext.push("/counter", String.valueOf(count));
}
```

First I tried to update counter with JS code and it worked:

```
<h:form>
   <h:outputText id="counter" value="#{bean.count}" styleClass="display" />
   <p:commandButton value="Click" actionListener="#{bean.increment}" />
</h:form>

<p:socket channel="/counter" onMessage="handleMessage" />

<script type="text/javascript">
            function handleMessage(data) {
                $('.display').html(data); 
            }
</script>
```

Example above works fine, but if I try to use ajax to update counter:

```
<p:socket channel="/counter" >
   <p:ajax event="message" update="@(.display)" />
</p:socket>
```

counter is not updated. There's no error/exception in portal (WAS 8) console, looks OK in Chrome, too. Only Firefox and IE display error messages, but I'm not sure what they mean.

Chrome console:
[image]

Firefox console:
[image]

IE console:
[image]

In FF console, when I click on 'counter:2:1' link, pushed data is displayed, like:

```
12|{"data":"4"}
```

Is this even the right response format?

PS: Using WebSphere Portal 7 (WAS 8), PF 4.0, Atmosphere runtime 2.0.1

Comment: How is this PF related if it is your custom component? (and where is the code?) And if there is a parseError, the cause is... a parseError (what is it? Post details etc)

Comment: @Kukeltje I used Socket and SocketRenderer from PF 4, that's why I didn't post this code. I can post it, but it's just a copy from PF 4. And it's not parseError, it's parsererror... Don't know what the cause is, I don't get any stack trace, just a JS error in Chrome or any other browser.

Comment: so you checked the contents of the response I assume... Was it well formed or not? How did it look like? Please investigate more. We cannot tell you all this...

Comment: @Kukeltje I just realized that counter example doesn't work with PF 4 either (when using ajax), so I changed a question a bit. I also added some response content if it helps. I'm not sure if it is well formed or not (I'm guessing it's not based on error description), I'm trying to find out. All POST/GET methods are executed with OK status, so I'm a little confused about the whole thing. Please let me know if there's any way to get some additional information...